# Powershell transcript for powershell 7

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-7.0

I've migrated to powershell 7 recently, but I can't make the powershell transcription working for powershell 7. (Legacy powershell transcription works fine though.)

The registry is this:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription
EnableTranscripting = 1
OutputDirectory = D:\logs

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription
EnableTranscripting = 1
OutputDirectory = D:\logs
```

And it does not work for powershell 7, and group policies (`Computer/User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows PowerShell`) have been set as well and it did not work.

Anyone knows how to make powershell 7 transcription works?

Comment: I suggest policy for `Computer Configuration` settings are kept in `HKLM`-hives and `User Configuration` - in `HKCU`.  Probably you should change registry path.

Comment: Have you read the manufacturer [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_config?view=powershell-7.3)? It says that the PS7 settings are stored in a `powershell.config.json` file. Old versions keep settings in registry.